# Get all rows inside a foreach loop and echo an array result?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to get all rows inside a foreach loop but it's not working as it should.

```
<?php 
foreach ($locations_loop as $row):

    $lr_id  = $row["id"];
    $stmtlr = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM locations_rating WHERE l_id = {$lr_id}");
    $stmtlr->execute();
    $stlr_loop = $stmtlr->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (empty($stlr_loop)) {
        $loc_rate[] = "0";
    } else {
        foreach($stlr_loop as $rowlr):
            $loc_rate[] = $rowlr["stars"];
        endforeach;
    }
    
    $rating_array = array_values($loc_rate);
    $rating_avg   = array_sum($rating_array) / count($rating_array);
?>      
<?=round($rating_avg, 1);?>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

$rating_avg outputs something else every time the script runs. It works fine outside a foreach loop tho. I tried to join the two table but no luck since it only outputs only one row.

Comment: 1. Do not prepare the sql statement inside the loop.  **The whole idea is that you prepare once, bind once, and then execute within the loop.**  2. Use placeholders with bound parameters. 3. Do not use `fetchAll()` if you are planning on looping through the result set in the same "layer" of your code.  4. Do not call `array_values()` on an array that is already indexed -- it changes absolutely nothing.

Comment: @mickmackusa Why no prepare inside loop. Much appreciated if you explain the drawback of that

Comment: Because doing something once is much easier then doing same thing again and again. Isn't it obvious?

Comment: 5. Upon closer inspection, I don't see why you need to make multiple trips to the db.  Use a `WHERE l_id IN (...)` with your `array_column($locations_loop, 'id')` array.  6. Summing and Counting is something that sql is perfectly capable of doing.  Move all of your processing and logic into the sql. 7. Only fetch data that you intend to use from the db table -- replace `*` with `stars`.

Comment: I get you and not at the same time :D If it not too much to ask, can you modify the code I posted above the way you explained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be thinking too far out of the box, but this is just one technique that occurred to me which will ensure that all location ids will receive an average value in the result set.

Assuming `$locations_loop` (a poor name for a variable containing array type data, tbh) has the following data:

```
$locations_loop = [
    ['id' => 1],
    ['id' => 2],
    ['id' => 3],
    ['id' => 4],
];
```

And you have a database table with the following schema: ([db-fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3uNQVmeD32scMDRvFQA9Pk/0))

```
CREATE TABLE `locations_rating` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `l_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stars` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `locations_rating` (`id`, `l_id`, `stars`) VALUES
(1, 3, 4),
(2, 2, 2),
(3, 1, 0),
(4, 2, 5),
(5, 3, 2),
(6, 1, 10);
```

Then you can get all of your data in one trip to the database by creating a "derived table" from your column of `id` values, then joining the database data to them.  Something like this:

```
SELECT def.l_id,
       ROUND(AVG(COALESCE(stars, 0)), 1) avg
FROM (
  (SELECT 1 AS l_id)
  UNION (SELECT 2)
  UNION (SELECT 3)
  UNION (SELECT 4)
 ) AS def
LEFT JOIN locations_rating AS loc ON def.l_id = loc.l_id
GROUP BY def.l_id
```

To do this with a prepared statement and bound parameters:

```
$locationIds = array_column($locations_loop, 'id');
$countIds = count($locationIds);

$fabricatedRows = implode(' UNION ', array_fill(0, $countIds, '(SELECT ? AS l_id)'));

$sql = "SELECT derived.l_id,
               ROUND(AVG(COALESCE(stars, 0)), 1) avg
        ($fabricatedRows) AS derived
        LEFT JOIN locations_rating as loc ON derived.l_id = loc.l_id
        GROUP BY def.l_id";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($locationIds);
var_export($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Should output:  (I tested this technique to be successful in my local environment)

```
[
    ['l_id' => 1, 'avg' => 5.0],
    ['l_id' => 2, 'avg' => 3.5],
    ['l_id' => 3, 'avg' => 3.0],
    ['l_id' => 4, 'avg' => 0.0],
]
```